# iPhone , Convert @Selector call whith IBAction

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector, ibaction

I have this code:

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *imgIcon = imageNamed(@"icon_1.png");
[btn1 setImage:imgIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

CGPointMake(textField.frame.size.width+textField.frame.origin.x+btnTalk.frame.size.width/2, textField.frame.origin.y+textField.frame.size.height/2);
[btnTalk addTarget:textField action:@selector(Hello:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btnTalk];
```

i can tap in UIbutton and it works 
but i want to call with other button
i want create one IBAction for call this  UIButton

i writes this code but doesn't work  & textfield is (objectOfAnotherClass)

```
-(IBAction)call1
{
    [textField Hello];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do like this:

```
[btnTalk addTarget:self action:@selector(Hello:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)call1
{
   [self Hello:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for `sendActionsForControlEvents` that helps you to 'simulate' the action of touching the button... [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendActionsForControlEvents%3a) the method description.